# Argument that the picture of P is in U

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I should argument that this is $P^2 = P$ because the  picture of P is in U.

can I argument that if I define this vector $v ∈ R^n and \ n ∈ N$

so $v = \left(\begin{matrix} 
a
\\b
\\c
\end{matrix}\right), U = span(v)$

and $ P = \left(\begin{matrix} 
a^2 & ab & ac
\\ab & b^2 & bc
\\ac & bc & c^2
\end{matrix}\right)$

and if I calculate $ U * P = U$

Or is there a better way to show that?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Do you mean "image" when you say "picture"? What means "that this is $P^2 = P$"? What is given?

Comment: P is a projection of some subspace U  $R^n$ and yes picture = image